# XSLT templates not working

Tags: c#, xslt

Despite reading lots of documentation on various websites about XSLT templates, I can't get to make XSLT working with my C# code.

Here is my working XSLT file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<BODY>
  <TABLE BORDER="2">
    <TR>
      <TD>First name</TD>
      <TD>Last name</TD>
      <TD>Age</TD>
    </TR>

    <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfUserModel/UserModel">
          <TR>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="Age"/></TD>
              </TR>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my non working XSLT file (the  and  processing has been moved to a template at the end of the stylesheet which should theoretically return the same but does not display any user info) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <HTML>
<BODY>
  <TABLE BORDER="2">
    <TR>
      <TD>First name</TD>
      <TD>Last name</TD>
      <TD>Age</TD>
    </TR>

    <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfUserModel/UserModel">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="user"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </TABLE>
</BODY>
  </HTML>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="user">
  <TR>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></TD>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></TD>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="Age"/></TD>
  </TR>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here the C# code that I use for the XSLT transform :
(I pass a serializable UserModel object containing some properties, and the content of the XSLT file, then it returns HTML)

```
    public static string TransformXml2(object data, string xslt)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
        string xml;
        using (StringWriter swr = new StringWriter())
        {
            xs.Serialize(swr, data);
            xml = swr.ToString();
        }

        // Simple data checks   
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Param cannot be null or empty", "xml");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xslt))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Param cannot be null or empty", "xslt");
        }

        // Create required readers for working with xml and xslt   
        StringReader xsltInput = new StringReader(xslt);
        StringReader xmlInput = new StringReader(xml);
        XmlTextReader xsltReader = new XmlTextReader(xsltInput);
        XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlInput);

        // Create required writer for output   
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter transformedXml = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        // Create a XslCompiledTransform to perform transformation   
        XslCompiledTransform xsltTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

        try
        {
            xsltTransform.Load(xsltReader, new XsltSettings(true, true), null);
            xsltTransform.Transform(xmlReader, transformedXml);
        }
        catch (XmlException xmlEx)
        {
            // TODO : log - "Could not load XSL transform: \n\n" + xmlEx.Message   
            throw;
        }
        catch (XsltException xsltEx)
        {
            // TODO : log - "Could not process the XSL: \n\n" + xsltEx.Message + "\nOn line " + xsltEx.LineNumber + " @ " + xsltEx.LinePosition)   
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO : log   
            throw;
        }

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
```

THank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax

```
select="user"
```

Means "find all child elements called 'user' and apply their matching template". There is no "user" element, hence no output.

Either *call a named template*, or apply a select that yields matches.

For example, instead of the for-each, you could:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfUserModel/UserModel"/>
```

And change the template to match UserModel:

```
<xsl:template match="UserModel">
```

Comment: Now, I'm trying to use an <xsl:include href="usermodel.xsl"> with the usermodel.xsl file being in the same local folder than the main XSL file, but VC# says : "URI External resolution is forbidden" or so in french.

Comment: @virrea that sounds like an unrelated question...?

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have made another question, which I will do. Thanks Marc, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try avoiding `for-each` and go for template usage all the way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
            <BODY>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ArrayOfUserModel">
        <TABLE BORDER="2">
            <TR>
                <TD>First name</TD>
                <TD>Last name</TD>
                <TD>Age</TD>
            </TR>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </TABLE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="UserModel">
        <TR>
            <TD><xsl:value-of select="./FirstName" /></TD>
            <TD><xsl:value-of select="./LastName" /></TD>
            <TD><xsl:value-of select="./Age" /></TD>
        </TR>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that by splitting the parts of the output concerning the document body, the general list layout (table) and the list items your xslt will become more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

**Most probably, in the XML document that is not shown in the question, no  `UserModel` element that is a child of `ArrayOfUserModel` has a `user` child**.

This is why this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="user"/>
```

cannot find any `user` element and thus no templates get applied.

**Solution**:

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfUserModel/UserModel">                
  <xsl:apply-templates select="user"/>        
</xsl:for-each>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfUserModel/UserModel"/>
```

**and change**:

```
<xsl:template match="user">
```

**to**:

```
<xsl:template match="UserModel">
```

**The complete code becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <HTML>
    <BODY>
      <TABLE BORDER="2">
        <TR>
          <TD>First name</TD>
          <TD>Last name</TD>
          <TD>Age</TD>
        </TR>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfUserModel/UserModel"/>

      </TABLE>
    </BODY>
      </HTML>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="UserModel">
      <TR>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></TD>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></TD>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="Age"/></TD>
      </TR>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```